# Как получить определённые данные?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api

я пропарсил данные с запроса, и получил их, как достать нужное значение всех?

```
 const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='https://api-argon.tfl.gov.uk/BikePoint';
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();


Http.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){   
    var bikePoint = JSON.parse(Http.responseText);
    var markerLat = bikePoint[0].lat,
        markerLon = bikePoint[0].lon;

    console.log(markerLat);
    console.log(markerLon);
    console.log(bikePoint);
      }
}
```

Вот так выглядит ответ

```
"$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.AdditionalProperties, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "category": "Description",
        "key": "NbDocks",
        "sourceSystemKey": "BikePoints",
        "value": "14",
        "modified": "2018-09-12T21:41:00.507Z"
      }
    ],
    "children": [],
    "childrenUrls": [],
    "lat": 51.488057,
    "lon": -0.140741
  },
```

Как отсюда, вытянуть lat и lon, Именно все значения, чтобы потом я могу закинуть все метки на карту?

Comment: У вас не валидная структура ответа. Возможно, вы не правильно ее скопировали. Покажите валидную структуру.

Comment: Вот такое я получаю -- $type
:
"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Place, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities"
additionalProperties
:
(9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
children
:
[]
childrenUrls
:
[]
commonName
:
"River Street , Clerkenwell"
id
:
"BikePoints_1"
lat
:
51.529163
lon
:
-0.10997
placeType
:
"BikePoint"
url
:
"/Place/BikePoints_1"

Comment: через console.log и там куча массивов от 0...99

Comment: Там не куча массивов, там один массив. И у вас все равно не верно указана структура ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Данный GET запрос возвращает массив объектов.

Значит, надо сделать вот так.

```js
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'https://api-argon.tfl.gov.uk/BikePoint';
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();


Http.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var bikePoints = JSON.parse(Http.responseText);

    bikePoints.forEach(f => {
      console.log(f.lat, f.lon);
      var coord = document.createElement('div');
      coord.textContent = f.lat + ' ' + f.lon;
      coords.appendChild(coord);
    });
    console.log('single', bikePoints[0].lat, bikePoints[0].lon);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="coords">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь, а можете подсказать, как сделать, чтобы циклически шло, чтобы добавить на карту

Comment: @Kentos У меня в примере есть цикл, он добавляет данные в DOM. В чем проблема в цикле добавить на карту?

Comment: Я новичок, и возможно мне не стоило бы задавать тут вопрос, а самому разбираться, но я не могу закинуть на карту метки . Вот иницилизация метки <Marker
    title={'The marker`s title will appear as a tooltip.'}
    name={'SOMA'}
    position={{lat: 37.778519, lng: -122.405640}} />

Comment: @Kentos В таком случае, задавайте новый вопрос. Укажите там вашу разметку html, код js, стили. Сделайте воспроизводимы пример. И вам обязательно помогут!